# Patching multiple ORM calls in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, orm

I have a service layer in my Django app, where I have some business logic and the corresponding data retrieval code. Now, when I am writing unit tests, I want to **mock out the calls to the ORM** so that I am testing **the service layer only**.

My service layer looks something like this:

```
from .models import Event

class EventService():

    def get_client_separated_events(self):
        # Some complex business logic goes here
        qs = Event.objects.all()
        # Some complex business logic here as well
        return foo
```

When I'm testing the `EventService` class, I'd want the calls such as `Events.objects.all()` to be mocked out totally. As of now, I'm using `patch` to achieve this:

```
class TestEventService(TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    cls.event_service = EventService()
    cls.dummy_events = [Event(id=1, name='n1', description='d1'), Event(id=2, name='n2', description='d2')]

@patch('foo.bar.Events.objects.all')
def test_get_all(self, get_events):
    get_events.return_value = self.dummy_events
    expected_events = self.event_service.get_all()
    self.assertListEqual(expected_Events, self.dummy_events, msg="Assertion failed for get_all method "
                                                                     "in Event Service")
```

However, there might be ten such different ORM calls and I don't want to write ten lines worth of `@patch` statements to mock them out. I read online that `@patch.multiple` can do this - but I don't quite know if this is the right way to go about it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can mock directly the ORM and return arbitrary results, I think it would be more efficient an insert fake data in the database using a library such as [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html#django) and leave the ORM calls unmocked:

```
class EventFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'myapp.Event'


class TestEventService(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.event_service = EventService()

    def test_get_all(self):
        expected = [EventFactory() for i in range(10)]
        self.assertListEqual(
            self.event_service.get_all(),
            expected)
```

At some point, you cannot mock everything, and if you mock ORM calls, you may end up with passing tests while your code is actually buggy (for example if you have a mistake in your `filter` or `exclude` statements.

If you can test it easily, and keep your test fast and efficient, I think you should avoid mocking something. In your case:

- You can easily create dummy data
- Your tests will still be fast if you use the ORM because Django by default uses an in-memory SQLite databse during tests, avoiding disk I/O.

Mocking would totally make sense in other situations though, such as retrieving data over the network using an HTTP API, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In our project, we're trying to decide when it's a good idea to mock out the ORM layer and when it isn't. Mocking the ORM layer makes the tests run way faster, but the tests are a bit more brittle.

To me, it seems like it's not worth mocking the ORM if there's any complexity in the queries. You should test complex queries against a test database with some sample data in it.

If you do have simple queries that you want to mock out, try the [django-mock-queries](https://github.com/stphivos/django-mock-queries) package. I contributed a decorator called `mocked_relations` that mocks out the stuff you're asking about: `Event.objects` and foreign key relations.

Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/stphivos/django-mock-queries/blob/master/examples/users/analytics/tests.py#L49) that shows how to use it. You can list several model classes that you want to mock out.

```
@mocked_relations(User)
class TestMockedApi(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.api = AnalyticsApi()

    def test_api_active_users_filters_by_is_active_true(self):
        active_user = MockModel(mock_name='active user', is_active=True)
        inactive_user = MockModel(mock_name='inactive user', is_active=False)

        User.objects.add(*[active_user, inactive_user])
        results = [x for x in self.api.active_users()]

        assert active_user in results
        assert inactive_user not in results
```